# null is not an object while evaluating current user in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, expo

im getting type error null is not an object evaluating firebase.auth().currentUser.uid 
I am trying to get the current user id and store it into firebase database using an if statement logic for whether the user is an agent or client.

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
 XXX
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const UserId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

export function login({ email, password }) {
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
}

export function signup({ email, password, displayName }) {
  firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((userInfo) => {
      console.log(userInfo);
      userInfo.user
        .updateProfile({ displayName: displayName.trim() })
        .then((user) => {
          if (this.state.checked == "first") {
            firebase
              .database()
              .ref("client/" + UserId)
              .child("client")
              .update({ email, displayName, UserId });
          } else {
            firebase
              .database()
              .ref("agent/" + UserId)
              .child("agent")
              .update({ email, displayName, UserId });
          }
        });
    });
}

export function subscribeToAuthChanges(authStateChanged) {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    authStateChanged(user);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`firebase.auth().currentUser` will be null when no user is signed in.  The error is telling you that is the case.  You shouldn't try to access any properties on it until the sign-in completes successfully.

When sign-in does complete, you will have a user object delivered to your callback, so there is not even a need to use `firebase.auth().currentUser` at all here.

```
firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((userInfo) => {
      console.log(userInfo);
```

In your code above, `userInfo.user` is that current user object.  Use it instead of `firebase.auth().currentUser`.

Comment: so how would i get the user id from userInfo.user?

Comment: Use its `uid` property just like currentUser.  It's a User object.